# Invalid Result in Python MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating a Python app that interfaces with a MySQL database. Upon running the query `SELECT * FROM privileges_groups`I am met with this error:

```
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM privileges_groups")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 472, in _handle_result
    raise errors.InterfaceError('Invalid result')
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: Invalid result
```

This only occurs under certain specific circumstances but I cannot narrow it down to what directly causes it. Other queries are run before this but they seem to be successful.

The code it occurs in:

```py
def GetPrivileges():
    """Gets list of privileges."""
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM privileges_groups")
    priv = mycursor.fetchall()
    if len(priv) == 0:
        return []
    Privs = []
    for x in priv:
        Privs.append({
            "Id" : x[0],
            "Name" : x[1],
            "Priv" : x[2],
            "Colour" : x[3]
        })
    return Privs
```

The queries ran before it

```py
def UserData(id):
    """Gets data for user. (specialised for user edit page)"""
    Data = GetUser(id)
    mycursor.execute("SELECT userpage_content, user_color, username_aka FROM users_stats WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", (id,))# Req 1
    Data1 = mycursor.fetchall()
    if len(Data1) == 0:
        return False
    Data1 = Data1[0]
    mycursor.execute("SELECT email, register_datetime, privileges, notes, donor_expire, silence_end, silence_reason FROM users WHERE id = %s LIMIT 1", (id,))
    Data2 = mycursor.fetchall()[0]
    #Fetches the IP
    mycursor.execute("SELECT ip FROM ip_user WHERE userid = %s LIMIT 1", (id,))
    try:
        Ip = mycursor.fetchall()
        if len(Ip) == 0:
            Ip = "0.0.0.0"
        else:
            Ip = Ip[0][0]
    except Exception:
        Ip = "0.0.0.0"
    #gets privilege name
    mycursor.execute("SELECT name FROM privileges_groups WHERE privileges = %s LIMIT 1", (Data2[2],))
    PrivData = mycursor.fetchall()
    #rest of the code focuses on formatting the data from mysql
```

Comment: without seeing your code, are you sure that mycursor is set? wjen you describe that ot occurs only occasionally, look if you close the cursor

Comment: Wouldn't a closed cursor raise a ProgrammingError rather than an Invalid result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,  as i said i donÄ't see your code.

but i think you had prior fetch one row and then reused the cursor.

you can put [`buffered` to true!](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html)

```
mycursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
```

This resolves your problem.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that is likely to be causing this issue (it only occurs when getting data for select specific users).